# Shimano XTR brake

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes

The master cylinder plug popped out--not the bleed plug with the alle[image]n

Comment: Warrantying it would be my first choice of action.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like your question got truncated - can you please use [edit] to finish it?   Did you find the plug?  Does it thread back in and tighten down?